# How to import tables from sql server through sqoop to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have hadoop, hive, sqoop installed. I imported the table from my database to hdfs but couldnt import it to hive. Do I need to configure any file in hive? Also when I browsed the web the configuration is shown for MySQL but I am using the driver jdbc:sqlserver.
Anyone please help me as I am stuck with this since many days.

Answer (score 3):

jdbc:mysql is for mysql and it won't work for sqlserver, i have tried using it and it was giving out errors.  I have tried the below command and it worked wonderfully.

Command – import

Copy data from Database Table to HDFS File System

In the example below, our database & hdfs configuration is:

- server name :- labDB
- database name :- demo
- SQL user name :- sqoop
- SQL password :- simp1e
- Driver Class Name :- com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
- Table :- dbo.customers
- Target Directory : /tmp/dbo-customer (HDFS Folder name)

Syntax:

```
  sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver-name \
      --username <username> \
      --password <password> \
      --driver   <driver-manager-class> \
      --table    <table-name> \
      --target-dir  <target-folder-name>
```

Sample:

```
  sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://labDB;database=demo" \
       --username sqoop  \
       --password simp1e \
       --driver   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \
       --table    "dbo.customer" \
       --target-dir  "/tmp/dbo-customer"
```

https://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/hadoop-sqoop-importing-data-from-microsoft-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import a table and see it in Hive using the --hive-import flag
Check if you have defined all the global variables, HADOOP_HOME, SQOOP_HOME and HIVE_HOME
If it doesn't work for you, in the meantime you can always use CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE syntax to make use of your imported data in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the specific --hive-import switch in the sqoop command line?

Sqoop import --connect ‘jdbc:sqlserver://sqlservername.mycompany.com;username=hadoop;password=hadoop;database=hadoop’ --table dataforhive **--hive-import**

Answer (score 0):

just create an external hive table on the path in hdfs. or use --hive-import

Any of the two should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, I could store my MYSQL table in the HDFS but couldn't store it in hive. I simple imported the table in hive using the following command without again storing it in the HDFS and it worked for me.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ipAddress:portNo/mysqldatabase --table mysqltablename --username mysqlusername --password mysqlpassword --hive-import --hive-table hivedatabase.hivetablename
```

Comment: This will also import it into HDFS, but inside the Hive Metastore's default directory, i.e. Hive is managing for you where the data is stored. This is related to the difference between CREATE TABLE and CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE. See this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991258/how-to-create-external-table-in-hive-using-sqoop-need-suggestions